Scriptable load testing tools with HTTP/2 Cleartext support
I am developing an API which can work over HTTP/2 Cleartext (when deployed on premises) as well as HTTP/1.1 and the usual HTTP/2.
Some responses come in multiple chunks, since not all information is available immediately
So I want to find a load testing tool which can:

support all these protocols;
wait for a specified chunk (it's OK if I have to specify the number but better by content).

It needs to run on Linux (and under WSL), not be limited to GUI or a web interface; ideally can be run in CI.
k6 and Gatling don't support h2c (though the Gatling link is from 2020, I couldn't find any newer information).
h2load and Vegeta support h2c, but it seems can't do the second.

Maybe Apache JMeter?
It doesn't support HTTP2 out of the box but there is HTTP2 Plugin for JMeter which can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
You can "wait" for the specific frame either using While Controller or JSR223 PostProcessor

The plugin does mention "Protocol: Choose HTTP or HTTPS", which seems to imply h2c support. I'll try it, thanks!

This section: https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#alpn mentions HTTP/2 (over cleartext, h2c)
